Unifi Dream Router-restrict S2S traffic to one local network
I have a unifi dream router configured with 2 local networks.  Network1 is my home network (192.168.1.0/24) and network2 is my home-business network (172.16.1.0/24).
I have a site to site (S2S) vpn set up with a remote lab using IPSec, route-based networking, IKE2, etc.  The lab is on 10.253.0.0/24.
(Lab) 10.253.0.0/24 <--S2S--> dreamrouter <---> 172.016.1.0/24 (network 2 - biz)
                                          <xxx> 192.168.1.0/24 (network 1 - home)  

I want to make sure the lab traffic can only reach the 172 network and cannot reach the 192 network.
Things I have discovered:

there is no firewall type that can target the S2S.  The S2S traffic "appears" on the local network unfiltered.
the FAQ on Ubiquiti help says the following which may imply we have little control over firewall rules for S2S


Do I need to manually create firewall rules or static routes for the VPN?
No, these are automatically created.
ref: https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002426234-UniFi-Gateway-Site-to-Site-IPsec-VPN

Things I tried so far:

set up an IP group with 10.253.0.0/24
configure the firewall with type LAN IN and to drop anything sourced from the IP Group to the Destination 192 network

Unfortunately I can login to the remote lab and ping servers on both 192 and 172 networks so the above is not working to block 10.253.0.x to 192.168.1.x.
Is there another way to target the remote lab in the firewall config?
Thanks, Mark.

ok, I finally got it.  It needs to be LAN OUT firewall type because it is from inside firewall outbound that needs to be blocked from a VPN.
Credit to wundertech - the final paragraph of this article was the clue.
https://www.wundertech.net/how-to-configure-unifi-firewall-rules/
